# How to auto-scroll text-view with desired scrolling speed?

Tags: android

I want to scroll a textView with desired speed. Just like rolling credits. I have a textView about 50 lines long and I want to scroll it SLOWLY. So it should scroll for 10 seconds when that activity starts. I have tried using following, but it did not work.

```
LinearInterpolator scrollInterpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
        Scroller scroller = new Scroller(this,scrollInterpolator);
        scroller.extendDuration(10000);//I thought this was 10 seconds
        text1.setScroller(scroller);
```

I have also tried following. It takes me to end of the 50 line textView, but it does not go there slowly.

```
            scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);

            }
        });
```

As you can see I have tried scrollview and using a scroller on textview.
I want the textview to scroll slowly, so user can read each line.
By the way I need only vertical scrolling, not horizontal. 
Thanks

Comment: use `ObjectAnimator` with `scrollY` property

Comment: hey, could you provide me with small code snippet please?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ObjectAnimator` to scroll smoothly

```
final ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scrollView, "scrollY", scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight() - scrollView.getHeight());
        objectAnimator.setDuration(10000);
        objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        objectAnimator.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. But it requires API level 16. My minimum is 9.Of course, I can change it. But, is there another way? That's why I was trying to use a scroller. That's API level 1 stuff

Comment: no no no, use `ObjectAnimator.ofInt` directly - and no need for any `addUpdateListener`

Comment: Hi pskink, I'm a bit confused, are you saying replace .ofInt in above answer code?

Comment: @quasars i already sent you https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html, did you read it at all? or just read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator

Comment: No. I will read it and get back to you. But Amir_P's suggestion worked well. So doing that

Comment: @quasars if you want to add number 5 for 6 times do you use 5+5+5+5+5+5 or just 5*6?

Comment: exactly, much more simple, isnt it?

Comment: yes you're right ;) . thanks for your advices @pskink